# My links / urls not working after change to HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

beginner here :). So I have a wordpress website on which I added some of my own database tables and php & sql scripts. Users can login on my website (independently of wordpress) and then add content into my database tables, which is then shown on the website.

I have just switched to HTTPS with a certificate from Let's encrypt and I have a big problem. The URL's to my pages (those which are NOT wordpress) are not working anymore and are showing a 404 error. I spent a week trying to fix the issue but I just can't do it with my limited skills. Here is some info below.

The script which is generating the pages has the following code:

`$testurl = 'https://www.example.com/test-pages/'.sanitize_title($row['c2']).'-'.$row['id'];`

In .htaccess, I have the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^test-pages/[_a-z0-9-]+\-{1}([0-9]+)$  /test-pages?id=$1 [P]
```

These two should properly rewrite the urls, right (though I'm not sure where $testurl is called, the line of code is just sitting there in my script)? The particular lines of code were written by somebody else, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but they worked for years with plain old http!

I think I took the proper steps to set up https and all the wordpress pages are working.

Also, interestingly, if I try to access the pages with http, it redirects to `https://www.example.com/test-pages?id=` , which I guess is the standard url created out of the database, which the scripts presented above used to overwrite. And it shows the page fine. So I can make things work linking to pages in that way, but I don't want that.

At this point I have no idea what to do, normally I manage to overcome such issues, but not this time. I searched stackoverflow for solutions too, but found nothing to make sense for me. Any ideas? Is the problem here, or somewhere else? Hopefully I managed to explain the issue properly and somewhat coherently. Thank you!

EDIT: I added the htaccess file. I don't know exactly what more I should add.

````
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^test-pages/[_a-z0-9-]+\-{1}([0-9]+)$  /test-pages?id=$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^test-profiles/[_a-z0-9-]+\-{1}([0-9]+)$  /test-profiles?id=$1 [P]

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
<files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from **.***.**.**
</files>
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit```
````

Comment: Please add your full .htaccess file content, and a proper explanation of what script files you are trying to target & where they are located.

Comment: @CBroe - Is that safe? By script files / location you mean the path to them?

Comment: What do you mean "is that safe"? You can hardly expect that anyone can help if you do not provide the information... Since you publish things there should be no reason why publishing such routing information should not be "safe", especially since no one knows the host name those settings belong to...

Comment: I am a beginner, have a little patience with me, I don't know what I'm doing :) I'll edit the file and post it

Comment: I added the htaccess file. I don't know exactly what more I should add.

Comment: Why are those rules using the `[P]` flag? And why are you rewriting to `/test-pages?id=$1`, and not just directly to the actual script names (which presumably would be `/test-pages.php?id=$1` here then)?

Comment: I played around with your suggestions and it's not working either way. Those two lines in htaccess were written by a guy I hired in the past to help me with some url rewriting (something I'll probably have to do again this time around) because I don't know anything about the server side of things.